# How to create component in Vue3 using TypeScript, Pug Template engine and Composition API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pug, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

When I am exporting components inside `<script setup lang="ts">` and using in `<template lang="pug">`, it's throwing error, defined but never used.
For example:

```
<template lang="pug">
div
  // In kebab-case e.g. hello-world also have same issue
  HelloWorld
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import HelloWorld from'@/components/HelloWorld.vue';
</script>
```

This is throwing
Error: ***'HelloWorld' is defined but never used***

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
<template lang="pug">
div
  // In kebab-case e.g. hello-world also have same issue
  HelloWorld
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import HelloWorld from'@/components/HelloWorld.vue';
</script>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  }
}
</script>
```

So, the main idea is that we should clearly define our components. According to  https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script we can use 2 script tags, if we need!

Hope it was useful